# Batch - Conditionally minimize the current window

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file that provides a user menu.  Works fine.

I also permit a commandline parameter to run the batch in automated mode (no need for the menu) - also working fine.  Auto mode runs thru the various menu options in a prescribed manner.

example:  myBatch.bat -a

Request: When the "-a" parameter is passed-in, I'd like to auto-run the batch file in minimized mode (i.e., in the taskbar), then exit, somewhat silently from the user.

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could invoke powershell to minimize the console window.

```
for %%I in (%*) do if /i "%%~I"=="-a" (
    powershell -window minimized -command ""
)
```

Comment: Thanks, rojo.  I have no experience with Powershell.  I was hoping a solution in the more familiar (to me) batch env.

Comment: That is the batch environment.  PowerShell is not just a shell that interprets scripts.  It can interpret individual commands as well.  In this example, I'm invoking a PowerShell command within a batch environment. The command I'm having PowerShell perform just happens to be nothing. It's the execution switch of `-window minimized` where the magic happens. Just save my example code in a `.bat` script and run it. You'll see. And if you want to restore the window from its minimized state, just `powershell -window normal -command ""`. Don't worry. The parent thread is still the `cmd` interpreter.

Comment: Huh!  You are right.  I dropped in that code as-is.  The batch is running minimized when called with "-a".  Nice!